# Excels Graphical Issue

Tags: excel, vba

So although Excel not being made to create programs in, I'm completing one. Rest of the workbook works great but facing an issue with a sub which I'm yet to find anyone else having: (Images at the bottom)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWoEc.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pGQN.png

The sub will look at sheet 1 where it will fill sheet 2 with data accordingly, then sheet 3 will take that data and analyse it and present it nicely to the user who ran it. The error occurs mid macro where it pulls bits of each sheet referenced and graphically merges them. Once the macro finishes it remains broken until you go onto sheet 2 then back to 3, for the users this isn't really what I wanted.

Unsure if this is a limiation of Excel or if there is a method to force excel to dedicate some memory to keeping sheet 3 intact?

Macro is fully below:
Please note where I am selecting sheets is where I was troubleshooting

```
'This Sub will help calculate the % of Role Recomeneded Training. It will decide if the training for selected user is complete
Sub CalculateTrainingAnaltics()
    
    '-------------------------------------Role Based Training Analysis-------------------------------------

    'Unprotect Sheets to allow for calculations and changes
    Sheets("UserAnalysis").Unprotect
    Sheets("TrainingMatrixRe-Work").Unprotect
    Sheets("ManageUsers").Unprotect

    'Declare global Variables
    Dim userToCal As String
    Dim rowToCal As String
    Dim roleNeeded As String
    Dim cellToCheckC As String
    Dim holdCellNumber As String 'Temp Var meant to be over written
    Dim calcol As String 'Column to place findings into
    Dim progressBar As Integer
    
    
    'Reset Progress Bar
    Sheets("UserAnalysis").Range("B30") = progressBar
    Sheets("UserAnalysis").Range("B31") = progressBar
    
    'Go Back To orignal Sheet and reset graphical issues
        Sheets("Dashboard").Select
        MsgBox "Calculation now starting"
        Sheets("ManageUsers").Select
    
    userToCal = Range("D5")
    'MsgBox userToCal & " Column to Calculate" 'Debug line
    
    'Loops to compare all training
    For i = 0 To 298
        
        progressBar = i
        Sheets("UserAnalysis").Range("B30") = progressBar
        
        
        holdCellNumber = "" ' Clear before every use
        cellToCheckC = "" ' Clear before every use
        
            holdCellNumber = i + 9
            cellToCheckC = "C" + holdCellNumber
            'MsgBox cellToCheckC 'Debug Message
        
        roleNeeded = Sheets("UserAnalysis").Range(cellToCheckC)
        
     
        'Go Back To orignal Sheet and reset graphical issues
        If i = 50 Then
            Sheets("Dashboard").Select
            Sheets("ManageUsers").Select
        End If
        
        
        If roleNeeded = 1 Then
            
            holdCellNumber = "" ' Clear before every use
            userToCal = Sheets("UserAnalysis").Range("D5") ' Re-applies before every use
            
                holdCellNumber = i + 5
                userToCal = userToCal + holdCellNumber
            
            
            If Sheets("TrainingMatrixRe-Work").Range(userToCal) = "" Then
                
                calcol = "" ' Clear before every use
                holdCellNumber = "" ' Clear before every use
                    
                    holdCellNumber = i + 9
                    calcol = "D" + holdCellNumber
                    Sheets("UserAnalysis").Range(calcol) = "Incomplete"
                
            Else
            
                calcol = "" ' Clear before every use
                holdCellNumber = "" ' Clear before every use
                
                    holdCellNumber = i + 9
                    calcol = "D" + holdCellNumber
                    Sheets("UserAnalysis").Range(calcol) = "Completed"
                
            End If
            
        Else
            
            calcol = "" ' Clear before every use
            holdCellNumber = "" ' Clear before every use
            
            holdCellNumber = i + 9
            calcol = "D" + holdCellNumber
            Sheets("UserAnalysis").Range(calcol) = "Not Needed"
            
        
        End If
    
    Next
    
    '-------------------------------------Training Compliance-------------------------------------------------------------------
   
    'Go Back To orignal Sheet and reset graphical issues
        Sheets("Dashboard").Select
        Sheets("ManageUsers").Select
    
    Dim placeCalcu As String
    Dim rowToPlace As String

        For i = 0 To 298
        
            progressBar = i
            Sheets("UserAnalysis").Range("B31") = progressBar
            
            'Go Back To orignal Sheet and reset graphical issues
            If i = 50 Then
                Sheets("Dashboard").Select
                Sheets("ManageUsers").Select
            End If
        
            holdCellNumber = "" ' Clear before every use
            userToCal = ""
                    
            userToCal = Sheets("UserAnalysis").Range("E5") ' Re-applies before every use
            holdCellNumber = i + 603
            userToCal = userToCal + holdCellNumber
            'MsgBox userToCal
                
            If Sheets("TM-TimeFormatting").Range(userToCal) = True Then
                        
                        'MsgBox "Checking OUT OF DATE"
                        
                        rowToPlace = ""
                        
                        placeCalcu = "E"
                        rowToPlace = i + 9
                        placeCalcu = placeCalcu + rowToPlace
                    
                        'MsgBox placeCalcu 'Debug Line
                        Sheets("UserAnalysis").Range(placeCalcu) = "Out Of Date"
                    
            Else
                'Now we'll pull if the data has expired or near EOL or 3 Months or More Left
                
                holdCellNumber = "" ' Clear before every use
                userToCal = Sheets("UserAnalysis").Range("E5") ' Re-applies before every use
                
                holdCellNumber = i + 304
                userToCal = userToCal + holdCellNumber
                
                'Test for if the training is out of date
                If Sheets("TM-TimeFormatting").Range(userToCal) = True Then
           
                        
                    placeCalcu = "E"
                    rowToPlace = i + 9
                    placeCalcu = placeCalcu + rowToPlace
                    
                    'MsgBox ("Checking") 'Debug Line
                    Sheets("UserAnalysis").Range(placeCalcu) = "Near EOL"

                Else
                
                    holdCellNumber = "" ' Clear before every use
                    userToCal = ""
                    
                    userToCal = Sheets("UserAnalysis").Range("E5") ' Re-applies before every use
                    holdCellNumber = i + 902
                    userToCal = userToCal + holdCellNumber
                    
                    If Sheets("TM-TimeFormatting").Range(userToCal) = True Then
                        
                        rowToPlace = ""
                        
                        placeCalcu = "E"
                        rowToPlace = i + 9
                        placeCalcu = placeCalcu + rowToPlace
                    
                        'MsgBox placeCalcu 'Debug Line
                        Sheets("UserAnalysis").Range(placeCalcu) = "Compliant"
                        
                    
                    Else
                
                        If Sheets("TrainingMatrixRe-Work").Range(userToCal) = 0 Then
                    
                        'Where to place not complete
                        placeCalcu = "E"
                
                        rowToPlace = i + 9
                        placeCalcu = placeCalcu + rowToPlace
                
                
                        'If its not then apply Not completed
                        Sheets("UserAnalysis").Range(placeCalcu) = "Not Completed"
                        End If
                        
                    End If
                    
                End If
                
            End If
        
            
        Next

    
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Refresh the pivot table and pie chart
    Dim Table As PivotCache
    
    For Each Table In ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches
    
        Table.Refresh
        
    Next Table
    
    'Go Back To orignal Sheet and reset graphical issues
        Sheets("Dashboard").Select
        Sheets("ManageUsers").Select
    
    'Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    'Complete Msg
    MsgBox "Calculation Complete - Please see information :)"
    'Sheets("ManageUsers").Select
    
    
    'Reprotect All of Working Sheets
    Sheets("UserAnalysis").Protect
    Sheets("TrainingMatrixRe-Work").Protect
    Sheets("ManageUsers").Protect
```

End SUB

Comment: How about [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72101403/edit) to include the code.

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).
• In which line does the error occur and what is the error message?

Comment: "the error" is not a really useful description of what happens when you run your code - you've posted a lot of code so we're not going to be able to guess what the problem is...

Comment: Also if it is graphical it is maybe a good idea to upload a screenshot of it.

Comment: Hi All, the error is described in the post: "The error occurs mid macro where it pulls bits of each sheet referenced and graphically merges them. ". Also this isn't a error which is fatal, the macro does finish and the sheet semi recovers, I have to select another sheet and then back onto the original. I'll upload a picture of the error

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. You can test it by using the same file on another computer with the same Excel version, or trying it on another Excel version. If it is a bug I would suggest to try the following: Set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in the beginning and `True` in the end of the macro (this might help). As a workaround you can use `Worksheet(…).Select` to switch sheets in the end of your macro. I think there is no other solution unless Microsoft fixes it if it is a bug.

Comment: Alright mate, thats what I feared to be honest but this freeze will do the job fine. Thank you!